# Blazor - how to get id of element from click event?

Tags: blazor

I have dynamic generation of that elements on markup

```razor
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="@(calendar[counter - 1].ToShortDateString())">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
        Add to report
    </label>
</div>
```

Its a possible get id of checkbox from click on it?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem...why do you need the ID? That being said, just write your own click handler and pass the ID as a parameter.

Comment: A comment: `ShortDateString` seems a strange string to use as an `id`. How do you guarantee it's unique.  If there's no specific reason - like you use it as a proxy that you use later, use something like a Guid as a string.  It will be unique!

Comment: yeap its XY probem